# ros2_control manage hardware_interface::return_type::ERROR

Tags: ros, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,
I am currently working with the foxy branch of `ros2_control` and trying to figure out how is the error management done by the `controller_manager` ?  If I understood correctly, when hardware fails the `hardware_manager` should return  `hardware_interface::return_type::ERROR` but the `controller_manager` keeps running. What is the best way to deal with this and either restart the hardware or the controllers ?
Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392309/ros2_control-manage-hardware_interface::return_type::error/) by [mcbed](https://answers.ros.org/users/91087/mcbed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

there is not and will not be any error management done by controller_manager for **`foxy`**. We integrated error management into rolling and we had to do many API and ABI breaks to do so. Therefore, it is not possible to back port this features to foxy.

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2022-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1